# Powershell Script says Completed but not doing anything

Tags: bash, powershell

I am writing a script that extracts 8 characters of folders name in a specific path, convert them into date and subtracts the date from the actual date. If the difference is higher than 30 days it moves them to a new location.

Evrytime I run the powershell script it says completed but nothing works.

My Execution policy is set to Bypass.

Here is the code:

```
# Specify the source directory path 
$sourceDirectoryPath = "C:\Users\aqel\Desktop\old"

# Specify the destination directory path
$destinationDirectoryPath = "C:\Users\aqel\Desktop\New"

# Specify the date difference threshold in days
$dateDifferenceThreshold = 30 

# Get a list of subdirectories within the source directory
$subdirectories = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectoryPath -Directory

# Get the current date
$currentDate = Get-Date

# Loop through each subdirectory
foreach ($subdirectory in $subdirectories) {
    # Extract the folder name
    $folderName = $subdirectory.Name

    # Extract the first 8 digits from the folder name
    $first8Digits = $folderName -replace "[^0-9]", ""

    # Check if there are at least 8 digits in the folder name
    if ($first8Digits.Length -ge 8) {
        # Extract year, month, and day from the first 8 digits
        $year = $first8Digits.Substring(0, 4)
        $month = $first8Digits.Substring(4, 2)
        $day = $first8Digits.Substring(6, 2)

        # Create a date from the extracted components
        $folderDate = Get-Date -Year $year -Month $month -Day $day

        # Calculate the difference between the two dates
        $dateDifference = ($currentDate - $folderDate).Days

        # Check if the date difference is greater than the threshold
        if ($dateDifference > $dateDifferenceThreshold) {
            # Construct the destination path
            $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $destinationDirectoryPath -ChildPath $folderName

            # Move the folder to the destination path
            Move-Item -Path $subdirectory.FullName -Destination $destinationPath -Force

            # Display the move operation
            "Moved folder '$folderName' to '$destinationPath' (Date Difference: $dateDifference days)"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "Folder name '$folderName' does not contain at least 8 digits."
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does what say "Completed"? There's nothing in your script that would write such a message. FWIW `$dateDifference > $dateDifferenceThreshold` should be `$dateDifference -gt $dateDifferenceThreshold`

Comment: This question should not be tagged `bash`; there is nothing Bash-related. Using the right tags will help others navigate through StackOverflow more efficiently.